# How to rewrite a router url?

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, router

I search the entire web to found solutions for rewriting an url from a custom action but nothing works.

I tried to put into global this :

```
<rewrite>
            <artist_list_index>
                <from><![CDATA[#artist/list/index#]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[artists]]></to>
                <complete>1</complete>
            </artist_list_index>
        </rewrite>
```

It gives me a 404 when i try to reach artist/list/index or artists route.

I tried to put this in gobal :

```
<routers>
            <artist>
                <rewrite>
                    <list>
                        <to>artists</to>
                    </list>
                </rewrite>
            </artist>
        </routers>
```

I can real artist/list/index but artists gives me a 404. I think i understand why by checking the _rewrite function. It's because this allow to override a function from a controller by forwaring a route to another.

Finally i tried to create my own router and then i get this error "**Front controller reached 100 router match iterations**
". So in global i added this :

```
<events>
            <controller_front_init_before>
                <observers>
                    <artist_rewrite>
                        <class>Confidential_Artist_Controller_Router</class>
                        <method>insertControllerRouter</method>
                    </artist_rewrite>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_before>
        </events>
```

Confidential_Artist_Controller_Router functions are :

```
/**
     * Initialize Controller Router
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function insertControllerRouter($observer)
    {
        /* @var $front Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front */
        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('artist', $this);
    }

    /**
     * @param Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request
     * @return bool
     * @throws Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception
     */
    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
    {
        if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }

        $requestPathInfo=trim($request->getPathInfo(),'/');

        if($requestPathInfo != 'artists'):
            return false;
        endif;


        $request->setModuleName('artist')
            ->setControllerName('list')
            ->setActionName('index');
        $request->setAlias(
            Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
            $requestPathInfo
        );


        return  true;
    }
```

Finally, here is my action controller definition :

```
    <routers>
        <artist>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Confidential_Artist</module>
                <frontName>artist</frontName>
            </args>
        </artist>
    </routers>
```

Can you help me please ? i don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how the function match works but i found a solution.

I changes this function in this :

```
public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
    {
        if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }

        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        if ($identifier == 'artists') {
            $request->setModuleName('artist')
                ->setControllerName('list')
                ->setActionName('index');
            $request->setAlias(
                Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                $identifier
            );
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I don't understand if this is follow the magento standards. Can you give me more precisions please ?